# Need proper use of sleep() in a thread task

Tags: c, pthreads

// The thread of the periodic task is running in an infinite loop. I have included a flag and sleep(), so that it executes only for a certain time and then goes to sleep. But, after the modification, I am not getting the output "executing thread" at all. Please suggest, how to modify the use of the sleep function so that I get the output "executing thread" for the time and then it goes to sleep.//

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int exitflag=0;

struct task_spec_struct 
{ 
    char task_type;
    int period,r_min,r_max;
}s1;

int gen_rand(int a, int b) 
{ 
    srand(time(NULL));
     int x = a+(rand()%(b-a));
      return x;
}

//task body to utilize CPU to perform computations

void* periodic_task(void* arg)
{
   struct task_spec_struct *arg_struct = (struct task_spec_struct*) arg;


  int rand_num = gen_rand(arg_struct->r_min, arg_struct->r_max);
  while(1)
    {
  int i, j=0;
  for(i=0; i<rand_num; i++)
  {
     j=j+i;

     }
     if (exitflag==1)
     {
     pthread_exit(0);
     }
  usleep((arg_struct->period)*1000);
  printf("Executing thread1");
  }

  //pthread_exit(0);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int num_args = argc-1;

// Creating pthread for periodic task ( runs Thread function to run periodically)
 // printf("\nGive task with specifications:");
  s1.task_type= 'P';
  s1.period= 300;
  s1.r_min= 400;
  s1.r_max= 500;

    pthread_t tid;
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_create(&tid, &attr, periodic_task, &s1);
        int ret=sleep(3);

  if (ret==0)
   {
       exitflag=1;
   }
  pthread_join(&tid, NULL);


}
```

Comment: Aside: move `srand(time(NULL));` to the start of `main`. Call it *once only* in the program.

Comment: Adding a newline to flush the printf output couldn't hurt...

Comment: Fixing the line `pthread_join(&tid, NULL);` wouldn't hurt either..

Answer (score 0):

printf does not flush by default unless you end the string with a newline character. See [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin).

You are not seeing the output because the buffer is not being flushed. Either add a new line character, or call fflush on stdout.